# How do I define local variables in a ConstructorBuilder?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'd like to make a constructor for my object built at runtime that calls a method that takes an object array of all the parameters passed to the ctor. Looking at how to build such a method it appears I have to do something like::

```
method pulbic hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor(SomeObject arg) cil managed
{
  ldarg.0
  call void MyNameSpace.BaseClass::.ctor();
  ldc.i4.1
  newarr System.Object
  stloc.0
  ldloc.0
  ldc.i4.0
  ldarg.1
  stelem.ref
  ldloc.0
  call void SomeClass.Method(object[])
  ret
}
```

Fairly straightforward, but how do I define a local variable of type `object[]` on the ctor builder? There doesn't appear to be a way to define variables, or do I just emit a `stloc.0/ldloc.0` and not care about defining it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you call `GetILGenerator()` and then use that to declare a local variable using `ILGenerator.DeclareLocal`?

Admittedly I haven't tried using any of this, but it *sounds* like it's the way to go...

Comment: wow, how the heck did I miss that! I think ref.emit still is a horribly clandestine api...